# os.execv PermissionError Errno13 Permission denied

Tags: python, permission-denied, execv

I am trying to run the same program recursively but with a different argument. I am doing it like this:

```
os.execv(file_dir, ['python'] + [sys.argv[0]] + [str(last_line)])
quit()
```

This is a snippet of a function that i call from my main function.
I tried making sure that that file is executable by doing `chmod u+x program.py` but that did not work. What can the issue be?

Comment: while you might get a response explaining how to do it, that seems like an antipattern. It is way better to write a function taking these parameters and call it as a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.execv` expects the **full** path to the executable as the first argument, not a "file directory".

Try this: `os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + [sys.argv[0]] + [str(last_line)])`

Example `yes` implementation by recalling the same executable:

```py
import sys
import os

print('y')
os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + [sys.argv[0]])
```

Comment: If I do that I get  ```can't open file 'program.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory```

Comment: That's probably because in the original call argv[0] is a relative path. Try `os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])`

Comment: BTW I tried printing out what sys.executable is and it is in usr/bin/python3 while my project containing the file I want to execute is in a folder on my Desktop

Comment: Ok ye you were right with your last comment. thank you so much. Now I am having another issue with import statements in the recursive subprogram but I will post another question for that